# Confused trying to convert a string to a JSON object in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

Maybe I haven't been sleeping well. I thought it would be straight forward by I can't convert a string to a JSON object.

In a specific controller action I'm doing something like:

```
def my_action
  user = User.find(current_user_id)
  profile = Profile.find_by(user_id: current_user_id)
  company = Company.find(id)
  colors = company.colors
  { id: user.id, username: user.username, email: user.email, profile: profile, company: company, colors: colors}
end
```

The variable `colors` comes form my Postgres DB inside a column with data type JSON, and results in the following output:

```
"{color0:[#2d2445,#433566,#5C4AB4,#685DF2,#6c6eff,#D6D3FB,#EAEAFF], color1: [#262474,#434595,#524FFF,#528fff,#71A3FF,#B0CCFF,#F1F6FF]}"
```

That output is then returned inside the main JSON object but it's served as a string. I'm trying to convert that string to JSON so it becomes an object inside the main object.

I've tried to do `JSON.parse(colors)` but I'm getting a parsing error:

```
JSON::ParserError: 767: unexpected token at '{color0:[#2d2445,#433566,#5C4AB4,#685DF2,#6c6eff,#D6D3FB,#EAEAFF], color1: [#262474,#434595,#524FFF,#528fff,#71A3FF,#B0CCFF,#F1F6FF]}'
```

Any idea on how to transform that string into a valid JSON object I can work with in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with ensuring that data in db is correct in the first place. JSON/JSONB columns in rails+postgres are (de)serialized out-of-the-box, `company.colors.class` should already be Hash, but it looks like at some point before saving it was converted to a string (also a valid json type, thus no errors at save).

In a legacy project this may happen because of double serialization during switching from text to json, if there's still `serialize :colors` and the column is already json. Or at some point earlier, may be it is incorrectly serialized at client side (json being invalid hits at that)

As a hack to revive existing semi-invalid data you can:

```rb
if company.colors.is_a?(String)
  company.colors = JSON.parse(
    company.colors.gsub(/(#[0-9a-fA-F]+)/, '"\1"').gsub(/\b(\w+):/, '"\1":')
  )
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Indeed I had a problem coming from data inserted in the DB manually as a string. I wasn't properly serialized.